# usar los components de sass en un proyecto externo

Tags: css, sass, scss, patrones-de-diseño

Buen día , cuando se habla de 'componets' en el patron "7 en 1" de sass, quiere decir que esos componentes van a ser reautilizados en el mismo proyecto o tambien se puede llevar a otros proyectos ??

Comment: con esos componentes te refieres a la carpeta components?

Comment: Si a esas mismas

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Las preguntas sin código no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas como realizar una pregunta y evitar que te la cierren.

Comment: A mí me hace sentido lo que propones @EduardFloresFlores pero estrictamente entiendo que esa arquitectura no está enfocada en reusar los partials en otros proyectos

Comment: Gracias @RuslanLópez ,creo que estas en lo cierto ,pensándolo bién  no se podria llevar a otro proyecto

Comment: No es que no se pueda, es que necesitarías seguramente algunas cosas de la carpeta base como variables con las fuentes, colores y cosas así.